# how can I mix objective-c objects (i.e UITextView) with pure c++ UI like DooleJump leadboard

Tags: c++, objective-c

How can I mix objective-c objects (i.e UITextView) with pure c++ UI like DooleJump leadboard, which is scrollable and the text in it is from system`font. Can somebody help me ..thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the relation between DooleJump leadboard being scrollable and using system fonts, and the use of C++.

Anyway, to answer the question, if you need to mix Objective-C and C++, use Objective-C++ (and rename all your files from ".m" to ".mm")

Comment: Maybe  you are right....But I still wonder if I can mix objective-c `objects with cpp UI.  not just call it and switch the view  ..~

Comment: Then I already answered your question: use Objective-C++ to mix C++ and ObjC.